# Code requirements for the proximity of Power outlets to wash machine water outlets?

Tags: water, receptacle, code-compliance, dryer, washing-machine

In a laundry room (in the USA) - is there a code in the NFPA - NEC for minimum distance the Dryer and Washer Electrical outlets must be placed from the washer water pipes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after doing some searching I found two posts very similar to what I needed.

The only code requirement seems to be the distance with in 6 feet of the dryer or washer - other than that no other requirement.

https://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?threads/proximity-of-washer-dryer-outlets-to-washer-valves-tub.33541/

Answer (score 2):

### Nope

While there is a *maximum* limit on how far away these receptacles can be, set in 210.50(C):

> **(C) Appliance Receptacle Outlets.** Appliance receptacle
>   outlets installed in a dwelling unit for specific appliances,
>   such as laundry equipment, shall be installed within 1.8 m
>   (6 ft) of the intended location of the appliance.

there is no minimum distance stated in the Code, as 210.52(F) has nothing in it that'd set such a minimum and Art. 406 enforces no minimum distance between general plumbing fixtures and electrical receptacles.